# Relative stacking with Linear Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have 6 images I want to display as 2 rows with 3 images in each. I'm using nested LinearLayouts to achieve this, and it works well except for one thing:

The height of the largest image dictates the size of the linear layout, meaning there is empty space a lot of the time. In other words, my problem is as follows:
[image]

I keep getting the layout shown on the left, and I want the layout shown on the right.

I am aware that you can just use GridView, but that will still prevent the exact layout shown on the right, so I'm at a loss really. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 2 rows of three columns, you need 3 columns of 2 rows. LinearLayouts would be fine, just to be sure set the Gravity of the individual cells to `Gravity.TOP`.

Answer (score 1):

You could equally achieve the whole grid using RelativeLayout instead of Linear. Each of your bottom row would just need android:layout_below and android:layout_alignLeft set to be the ImageView above it.